# Devise + OmniAuth Saml: ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, saml, saml-2.0

I am using Devise with OmniAuth for Saml.
Saml callbacks do not post csrf token back and hence I get this error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken at /users/auth/saml/callback
```

So, to prevent CSRF check for my SAML call back, I added the `:except` for `saml` method.
But that doesn't seem to work. What would be a way for me to prevent CSRF checks for SAML callbacks with Devise and OmniAuth?

Here is my `OmniauthCallbacks` controller:

```
class Auth::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  protect_from_forgery :except => [:saml]

  def saml
    response = OneLogin::RubySaml::Response.new(params[:SAMLResponse])

    raise response.to_yaml

    # if response.is_valid?
    #   redirect_to root_url
    # end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm in a codebase that gets around this by using this bit at the top of controller:

`skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`